# Consulta SQL para unir tablas con columnas del mismo nombre

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Hola amigos espero y me puedan ayudar no tengo mucha experiencia con las consultas de SQL uniendo tablas con inner join o left join.

Tengo 2 talbas en las cuales quiero que me relacione los datos mediante el idCliente

> 1.- clientes (RazonSocial, RFC, Calle, Colonia, Municipio, Estado, CP)
>
> 2.- merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total)

Esta es la consulta que tengo hasta el momento pero me dice que varios campos son ambiguos (**`idCliente, rfc, FechaAlta y RFC`**)

```
SELECT idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total, RazonSocial, RFC, Calle, Colonia, Municipio, Estado, CP
FROM merca M, clientes C
WHERE C.idCliente=M.idCliente;
```

Comment: si te fijas en el from tienes las tablas merca y clientes, cada una con su alias M y C, en que momento en el select especificas que idCliente, rfc, FechaAlta y RFC se seleccionan de que tabla.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, deberías utilizar bien los alias para que evites problemas de ambigüedades.
Si quieres mostrar solo las mercadería que tengan cliente (que no sea nulo) entonces deberás usar INNER JOIN o JOIN que son lo mismo. Pero si quieres mostrar los registros así contenga valores nulos deberás usar LEFT JOIN o RIGHT JOIN.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT
    M.idViaje,
    C.idCliente, C.RazonSocial, C.RFC, C.Calle, C.Colonia,
    C.Municipio, C.Estado, C.CP
    M.importe, M.TipoOperacion, M.FechaAlta, M.detalles, M.TipoTransporte,
    M.FechaSalida, M.FechaLlegada, M.folio, M.porigen, M.eorigen, M.corigen,
    M.pdestino, M.edestino, M.cdestino, M.poliza, M.cuota, M.prima, M.gastosexp,
    M.iva, M.total, M.RazonSocial, M.RFC, M.Calle, M.Colonia, M.Municipio, M.Estado,
    CP
FROM merca M,
LEFT JOIN clientes C ON M.idCliente = C.idCliente;
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

El error que muestra tu consulta es basicamente por que tus dos tablas comparten columnas que tienen el mismo nombre, entonces estas al indicarlas en el SELECT el motor de base de datos no sabe a que columna estas intentando representar.
Ahora bien, si quieres tomar este resultado y pasarlo a algun front, te recomiento utilizar alias, asi puedes indicar la columna especifica. Esto ultimo se hace despues del nombre de la comlunma, asi: `clientes.rfc AS rfc_cliente`
Sería algo asi

```sql
SELECT  clientes.RazonSocial, clientes.RFC, clientes.Calle, clientes.Colonia, 
        clientes.Municipio, clientes.Estado, clientes.CP,
        merca.idViaje, merca.idCliente, merca.Cliente, merca.rfc, merca.moneda, 
        merca.mercancia, merca.importe, merca.TipoOperacion, merca.FechaAlta, 
        merca.detalles, merca.TipoTransporte, merca.FechaSalida, merca.FechaLlegada, 
        merca.folio, merca.porigen, merca.eorigen, merca.corigen, merca.pdestino, 
        merca.edestino, merca.cdestino, merca.poliza, merca.cuota, merca.prima, merca.gastosexp, 
        merca.iva, merca.total
FROM clientes join merca ON clientes.idCliente = merca.idCliente
```

Espero pueda ayudarte

Comment: Excelente amigo muchas gracias

Comment: de nada, recuerda calificar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta SQL debería especificar de que tabla esta obteniendo cada uno de los datos, para evitar amiguedades:

```
SELECT M.idViaje, M.idCliente, M.Cliente, M.rfc, M.moneda, 
M.mercancia, M.importe, M.TipoOperacion, M.FechaAlta, M.detalles, 
M.TipoTransporte, M.FechaSalida, M.FechaLlegada, M.folio, 
M.porigen, M.eorigen, M.corigen, M.pdestino, M.edestino, M.cdestino,
M.poliza, M.cuota, M.prima, M.gastosexp, M.iva, M.total, C.RazonSocial,
C.RFC, C.Calle, C.Colonia, C.Municipio, C.Estado, C.CP 
FROM merca M, clientes C 
WHERE C.idCliente=M.idCliente;
```

Adicional a ello, puedes ponerle un "alias" a las columnas que tienen el mismo nombre, para que luego puedes referenciarlas, de la siguiente manera:

SELECT M.idViaje, M.idCliente, M.Cliente, **M.rfc rfc_merca**, M.moneda, M.mercancia, M.importe, M.TipoOperacion, M.FechaAlta, M.detalles, M.TipoTransporte, M.FechaSalida, M.FechaLlegada, M.folio, M.porigen, M.eorigen, M.corigen, M.pdestino, M.edestino, M.cdestino, M.poliza, M.cuota, M.prima, M.gastosexp, M.iva, M.total, C.RazonSocial, **C.RFC rfc_cliente**, C.Calle, C.Colonia, C.Municipio, C.Estado, C.CP FROM merca M, clientes C WHERE C.idCliente=M.idCliente;

De ese modo podrás decirle explicitamente lo que buscas en la Query MYSQL para que te regrese unos datos que puedas manipular sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

No es mi intención ponerme demasiado teórico pero, respondiendo al pie de la letra a tu pregunta, estaríamos hablando de la operación NATURAL JOIN, que podrías implementar así:

```
SELECT * FROM FROM merca NATURAL JOIN clientes;
```

Como combina por todos los campos que tengan el mismo nombre, no habrá ambigüedad, el dato resultante es idéntico. Eso sí, igual no es a lo que te referías cuando formulaste la pregunta.